# Why can't I target a specific div with my userscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I'm trying to modify http://play.google.com/music/ with a userscript through Tampermonkey on Chrome, and I've hit a wall trying to target a specific div on the page - something seems to be preventing me from modify it.

You'll need to log into a google account (and maybe add a song if you don't have any) to see, but it would appear that the element

```
<div class="new-listen-now g-content three-column" style="opacity: 1;">
```

and all it's children are totally unable to be targeted by my script. Here's what the script looks like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Google Play Music Tweaks
// @description:en My personal tweaks for Google Play Music
// @namespace      www.reaverxai.com
// @require       http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js
// @include       http://play.google.com/music/listen*
// @include       https://play.google.com/music/listen*
// @include       http://music.google.com/music/listen*
// @include       https://music.google.com/music/listen*
// @match         http://play.google.com/music/listen*
// @match         https://play.google.com/music/listen*
// @match         http://music.google.com/music/listen*
// @match         https://music.google.com/music/listen*
// @run-at        document-end
// ==/UserScript==

$('.nav-toolbar').attr( "class", "testclass");
$('.recommended-header').attr( "class", "testclass");
```

The first line of jQuery works fine, as you'd expect it to, but the second, which targets a child element of the one mentioned above, doesn't do anything.

Comment: You should use `.addClass('myClass');` Is `'.recommended-header'`correct ? Is it present in the DOM ?

Comment: Are those elements present in the page on DOM ready, or are they appended dynamically afterwards? If it's the latter, there's your problem.

Comment: @Lauromine `attr( 'class', 'myClass')` != `.addClass('myClass');`

Comment: @Hacketo Oh, I did not know that, i'll take a look

Comment: @Lauromine `attr` will set the attribute, `addClass` add a class to the list, but maybe OP do not know that and want `addClass`

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to confirm something like that, but I had a feeling that might be the issue. Is there a way to wait until all of the page is completely finished, and then run the script? I've tried a few ways I saw to do this to no avail.

And yes, I want to replace the class, not just add a new one.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably being loaded by a script, so there's no specific event that will be fired when it's completed.  Your best bet would be to create an interval and check for that element, destroying the interval when it's in the DOM...

```
function whenElementLoaded() {
    // whatever you want to do when the element exists
}

var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    if ($(".new-listen-now.g-content.three-column").length) {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        whenElementLoaded();
    }
}, 500);
```

I've never been 100% happy with this approach when I've had to use it in the past, but it does do the trick and it does clean up after itself.  It should do what you need.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Much love. I can see how it's not the most elegant solution imaginable, but for my purposes, it's an A+.

Comment: Glad it could help :)

Answer (score 0):

### Wait for DOM ready state

Use jQuery's [`.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) method to invoke your function after the DOM is fully loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav-toolbar').attr("class", "testclass");
    $('.recommended-header').attr("class", "testclass");
});
```

This won't work if the target element is loaded dynamically later, in which case [Archer's answer on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32502981/2502532) may work well for you.

Also, if you can identify a specific event that triggers the addition of the target element to the DOM, you can bind your own delegated event handler to it with jQuery's [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method.